# Magento 2 | Blocks don't appear

Tags: magento2, xml, cms-block

I created a new page layout for my home page.
I want it to display 3 blocks next to each other.

It should look like this:

[image]

I created the blocks in backend but with the below code they don't show up.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <!-- 
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>

        <container name="fourth.column" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="fourth-column" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">Nummer 3</argument> 
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        -->

        <container name="column1" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column-float-left" after="-">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="startseite_links">
            <!-- 
            <arguments>
                <argument name="startseite_links" xsi:type="string">cmsblock-identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
            -->
        </block>
        </container>

        <container name="column2" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column-float-left" after="-">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="startseite_mitte">
            <!--
            <arguments>
                <argument name="startseite_mitte" xsi:type="string">cmsblock-identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
            -->
        </block>
        </container>

        <container name="column3" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column-float-left" after="-">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="startseite_rechts">
            <!--
            <arguments>
                <argument name="startseite_rechts" xsi:type="string">cmsblock-identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
            -->
        </block>
        </container>

    </referenceContainer>

</layout>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why arguments codes are commented out?

Comment: Can you share any screenshot how it should looks?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: And where are changing these? Is this for only one page?

Comment: it's only for the starting site

Comment: starting site means home page?

Comment: yes sorry, I am german^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83781/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-k33n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the requirement you are telling you can achieve it by 2 methods:

**Method 1:**
You can paste the below content in your CMS homepage:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_1"}}
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_2"}}
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_3"}}
```

This will show all your CMS static blocks**(block_1,block_2 and block_3)** together in the CMS homepage content area.

**Method 2:**

You can merge the contents of 3 CMS static blocks**(block_1,block_2 and block_3)** and paste the html into your CMS homepage content area.

Both will work same.

Comment: is there a way to add a widget to one of these blocks?

Comment: Yes of course. You can call widget into your CMS block of directly into the CMS homepage. Do you want the code?

Comment: Okay, how can I do that?

Comment: If you goto your cms page, you can find there is an option to add widget in your editor. Click on that and add your required widget.

Comment: Welcome! Happy coding!